# Banff to Vancouver via Kootenay and Okanagan valley in three days: does it make sense?

Tags: planning, driving, routes, british-columbia

In July I'll spend some days in Banff, and a few days after that I'll need to catch a flight in Vancouver. I would like to spend as many days as possible in Vancouver, so I'd like to keep the trip fairly short.

The shortest possible route seems to be the Trans-Canadian stopping one night somewhere in the Okanagan valley, Kelowna or similar.

But I've read really good things of the Kootenay Valley and I now have this crazy idea to split it in three days like this:

- Banff to Nelson via route 93
- Nelson to Vernon via route 6
- Vernon to Vancouver

My questions are:

1. Does this diversion make some kind of sense or is it just an insane amount of driving for no reason?
2. Google Maps says the transfer times for these segments would be around 6/7 hours each; are these estimates accurate or reliable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done the Calgary to Vancouver drive several times non-stop. I'd budget about 14 hours driving from Banff to Vancouver. That allows you to stop a couple of times. The Google Maps estimates are pretty accurate.